# aspx c# extra semi colon appear with inline if statement on onclick event

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement, syntax, onclick

I'm having trouble with C# inline if statement in aspx page, I'm trying to call a different onClick method depending if my Parent has Child or not, however, for some reason, it adds a ; in the code but the function is never called, however, with the same if statement in a text field, everything shows fine without any semicolon.

Any idea why?

Here are both OnClick and text code snippet:

```
OnClick='<%#(int)Eval("nbChild") != 0 ? "Expend" : "AddSub" %>'

Text='<%#(int)Eval("nbChild")!=0 ? "Expend":"AddSub" %>'
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please include a larger fragment of the markup in your question. Try to wrap the control (button?) with an html-tag (eg. a div) to ensure it gets rendered  by that control.

Comment: OnClick takes an event handler, not a string. So you can't conditionally change the event handler like that. But you can change your event handler so that it looks at the criteria and then calls different methods (or does different things) based on that criteria.

Comment: thank you so much Mason, that's what i did and it works well now